# Android: OnEditorActionListener not woking

Tags: android-edittext

I see some of post and make code to detect the event on "DONE" key pad button.
  But when implement it the keycode return the 6 and event return the null.is there any why to detect the DONE button event,i want to change focus.

```
textEdit5.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) { 
      if(arg1 == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION){
        btnSave.requestFocus();
        return true;
      }

      return false;     
    }
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please check this it out http://dev.bostone.us/2009/11/04/android-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-programmaticaly/#awp::2009/11/04/android-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-programmaticaly/

> if you want to set focus on button then btnSave.requestFocusFromTouch();

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.